# Expecting integer values in calculation, but getting <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on implementing an ID3 algorithm in python. In order to get past the first step I need to calculate the information gain per column. The comments are self-explanatory.

The issue that I am trying to resolve is

```
print(type(gain))
            print(f"gain for {columnName} = {gain}")
```

From the simple program shown below.

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import count
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
from math import ceil, floor, log2
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from numpy import linalg as LA
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

def calculate_metrics(tp, tn, fn, p, n, fp):
    # calculate the accuracy, error rate, sensitivity, specificity, and precision for the selected classifier in reference to the corresponding test set.
    accuracy = tp + tn /(p+n)
    error_rate = fp + fn /(p + n)
    sensitivity = tp/ p
    precision = tp/ (tp+fp)
    specificity = tn/n

    display_metrics(accuracy, error_rate, sensitivity, precision, specificity)

def display_metrics(accuracy, error_rate, sensitivity, precision, specificity):
    print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy}, Error_rate:{error_rate}, Sensitivity:{sensitivity}, Precision:{precision}, specificity:{specificity}')

def mc(columnName,training_set):
    # print(f'Column Name :{columnName}')
    # print(f'Column Contents: {training_set[columnName]}')
    column = training_set[columnName]
    probs = column.value_counts(normalize=True)
    # print(f'Probability {probs}')
    messageConveyed = -1*np.sum(np.log2(probs)*probs)
    # print(f'mc {messageConveyed}')
    return messageConveyed

def ID3(threshold,g):
    # use the training set to predict the test set.
    # use the Training set to extract rules and test the quality of the extracted rules against the Test set for ID3.
    test_set = pd.read_csv("Test set for ID3.csv")
    training_set = pd.read_csv("Training set for ID3.csv")

    print('***********************************')
    print('TRAINING SET')
    print(training_set)
    print('***********************************')


    print('***********************************')
    print('TEST SET')
    print(test_set)
    print('***********************************')

    print(f'test_set: {test_set}')
    print(f'training_set: {training_set}')

    # Step 1- Calculate MC (Message Conveyed) for the given data set in reference to the class attribute
    print(f'Step 1- Calculate MC (Message Conveyed) for the given data set in reference to the class attribute')
    # MC = -p1*log2(p1) - p2*log2(p2)
    # For n classes MC = -p1log2(p1) - p2*log2(p2)-...-pn*log2(pn)

    # For each column calculate the gain.
    numberOfColumns = 0
    mcDictionary = {}
    print('***********************************')
    print('For each column calculate the gain.')
    for (columnName, columnData) in training_set.iteritems():
        messageConveyed = mc(columnName,training_set)
        mcDictionary.update({columnName:round(messageConveyed)})
        numberOfColumns+=1
    print('***********************************')
    print(f'numberOfColumns {numberOfColumns}')
    print(f'mcDictionary {mcDictionary}')
    
    # The column with the highest gain is the root.
    print(f'The column with the highest gain is the root.')
    values = mcDictionary.values()
    max_value = max(values)
    print(f'The max value is {max_value}')
    # print(f'The max value, {max_value}, is associated with column {columnWithMaximumInformationGain}')
    val_list = list(values)
    columnWithMaximumInformationGain = list(mcDictionary.keys())[list(mcDictionary.values()).index(max_value)]
    print(f'The max value, {max_value}, is associated with column {columnWithMaximumInformationGain}')
    root =  training_set[columnWithMaximumInformationGain]
    print(f'root {root}')   

    # Loop
    # Step 2 - Repeat for every attribute
    print(f'Step 2 - Repeat for every attribute')
    for (columnName, columnData) in training_set.iteritems():

        # i) use the atttribute as a node from which k 
        # k branches are emanating, where k is
        # the number of unique values in the attribute
        attribute = columnName
        k         = training_set[columnName].nunique()
        print("*****************************************")
        print("**************** i  *********************")
        print(f'use the atttribute {columnName} as a node from which {k}')
        print(f'{k} branches are emanating, where {k} is')
        print(f'the number of unique values in the attribute')

        # ii) split the given data source based on the
        # unique values in the attribute
        print("*****************************************")
        print("**************** ii *********************")
        print(f'split the given data source based on the')
        print(f'unique values in the attribute: {columnName}')
        df1 = training_set[training_set[columnName] >= k]
        df2 = training_set[training_set[columnName] < k]

        print("**********")
        print("splitting ")
        print(f'df1 {df1}')
        print(f'df2 {df2}')
        print("**********")

        # iii) calculate MC for new splits
        # calculate MC for each  attribute of Venue
        print("*****************************************")
        print("************* iii ***********************")
        print(f"calculate MC for new splits")
        print(f"calculate MC for each  attribute of {columnName}")
        messageConveyed = mc(columnName,training_set)
        print(f"MC for {columnName} is {messageConveyed}")

        # iv calculculate the weight for each split
        # start with venue
        print("*****************************************")
        print("************* iv  ***********************") 
        print(f"calculculate the weight for each split ({columnName})")
        # Loop 
        # For each unique value calculate unique_value/total
        uniques1 = df1[columnName].unique()
        uniques2 = df2[columnName].unique()
        total1   = df1.count()
        total2   = df2.count() 

        print("*****************************************")
        print("*************  v  ***********************") 
        print(f"calculate the weighted MC (WMC) for the attribute ({columnName})")
        print("*****************************************")
        print("************* weights for df1  ***********")
        print(f"WMC({columnName})")
        for unique_value in uniques1:
            weight = unique_value/total1
            wmc = weight*mc(columnName,df1)
            print(f"+= {wmc}")

        # v) calculate the weighted MC (WMC) for the attribute
        # WMC(venue) = W(1)*MC(1) + W(2)*MC(2)
        print("*****************************************")
        print("*************  v  ***********************") 
        print(f"calculate the weighted MC (WMC) for the attribute ({columnName})")
        print("*****************************************")
        print("************* weights for df2  ***********")
        print(f"WMC({columnName})")
        for unique_value in uniques2:
            weight = unique_value/total2
            messageConveyed = mc(columnName,df2)
            wmc += weight*messageConveyed
            print(f"+= {wmc}")
            # vi) Calculate Gain for the attribute [MC-WMC(venue)]
            # Gain(venue) = MC-WMC(venue)
            print("*****************************************")
            print("*************  vi  **********************") 
            print(f"Calculate Gain for the {columnName} [{messageConveyed-wmc}]")
            gain = messageConveyed-wmc
            print(type(gain))
            print(f"gain for {columnName} = {gain}")
        

        # Step 3- Repeat for each split produced by the root
        # if all records have the same class then break. 

        # Step 4- If every split is free of a mixture of class values, then stop
        # expansion of the tree

        # Step 5- Extract rules in form of if-then-else from the tree
    
    # select the max value from the gain array
    # this is the new root



    # # leaf generated from the decision tree.
    # F1 = 0

    # # define c1 count of records w/ dominant class in F1
    # # How do I determine the number of records w/ dominant class in F1?
    # c1 = 0

    # # alpha = c1/ |F1|
    # # F1 is one of the unique values of a given attribute.
    # alpha = c1/ abs(F1)

    # # the number of records in the test set that are correctly classified by the rules extracted from the tree before removal.
    # # How do I determine the number of records in test set that are correctly classified by rules extracted from the tree before removal?
    # N = 0

    # # the number of records in the test set that are correctly classified by the rules extracted from the tree.
    # # How do I determine the number of records in the test set that are correctly classified by the rules extracted from the tree?
    # M = 0

    # # the parameter and 0 <= g <= 0.15
    # g = 0

    # if g < 0 or g > 0.15:
    #     exit()

    # # k is the total number of branches in the subtree
    # # How do I determine the total number of branches in the subtree?
    # k = 0

    # if alpha > threshold:
    #     # stop splitting tree

    # # How do we apply prepruning to the data?

    # # For post-pruning use the criteria below
    # if (N-M)/Q < g*k:
    #     # remove subtree
    
    # # true positive
    # tp = 0 
    # # true negative
    # tn = 0
    # # postive
    # p  = 0
    # #  negative
    # n  = 0
    # # false positive
    # fp = 0

    # calculate_metrics(tp, tn, p, n, fp)

def BayesClassifier():
    # use the assignment 2-- training set for Bayes as the training set to classify the records of the assignment 2 test set for bayes
    test_set = pd.read_csv("Assignment 2--Test set for Bayes.csv")
    training_set = pd.read_csv("Assignment 2--Training set for Bayes.csv")


# prompt user to select either ID3 or Bayes classifier.
selection = "ID3" #= input("Please enter your selection for either ID3 or Bayes classification: ")
threshold = 0.9   #= input("Please enter a threshold: ")
g         = 0.5   #= input("Please enter a value for g: ")

if(selection == "ID3"):
    ID3(threshold,g)

if(selection == "Bayes"):
    BayesClassifier()
```

The Test set for ID3.csv

```
Venue,color,Model,Category,Location,weight,Veriety,Material,Volume
1,6,4,4,4,1,1,1,6
2,5,4,4,4,2,6,1,1
1,6,2,1,4,1,4,2,4
1,6,2,1,4,1,2,1,2
2,6,5,5,5,2,2,1,2
1,5,4,4,4,1,6,2,2
1,3,3,3,3,1,6,2,2
1,5,2,1,1,1,2,1,2
1,4,4,4,1,1,5,3,6
1,4,4,4,4,1,6,4,6
2,5,4,4,4,2,4,4,1
2,4,3,3,3,2,1,1,1
2,6,5,5,5,1,4,2,1
```

The Training set for ID3.csv

```
Venue,color,Model,Category,Location,weight,Veriety,Material,Volume
1,6,4,4,4,1,1,1,6
2,5,4,4,4,2,6,1,1
1,6,2,1,4,1,4,2,4
1,6,2,1,4,1,2,1,2
2,6,5,5,5,2,2,1,2
1,5,4,4,4,1,6,2,2
1,3,3,3,3,1,6,2,2
1,5,2,1,1,1,2,1,2
1,4,4,4,1,1,5,3,6
```

Expected:
An integer value i.e. `gain for Volume =       2.090259`

Actual:

```
gain for Volume = Venue       2.090259
color       2.090259
Model       2.090259
Category    2.090259
Location    2.090259
weight      2.090259
Veriety     2.090259
Material    2.090259
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]. You've given us a massive 248-line dump with all sorts of unnecessary code and commented out parts. Please distill it down to show what the actual problem is. Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect. We should be able to paste a single block of your code into a file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Also, please send the full traceback.

Comment: Creating a minimal reproducible example from jumbled code like this forces you to go through it line by line, pare out the fluff (like formatting for user input), and actually *think* about the logic. A lot of the time, you can find the bug(s) right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in calculating totals. The dataframe needs to use the `columnName` as the index.

```
        uniques1 = df1[columnName].unique()
        uniques2 = df2[columnName].unique()
        total1   = df1[columnName].count()
        total2   = df2[columnName].count()
```